# Rewrite url in htaccess accept character?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have url is :

> domain.com/search?category=&q=title+product

now I want redirect to

> domain.com/tim-kiem=title+product

I process it **.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^search\?category=\&q=(.*)$ domain.com/tim-kiem-$1.html [R,L]
```

However it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query part of your URL is matched by the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bq=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ /tim-kiem=%1? [R,L]
```

Comment: It had working. however I not understand. Please help clarification step by step